# How to restrict printing INFO and ERROR messages in Travis log file?

Tags: logging, travis-ci

I am using Travis CI for my build deployment process. I observed `INFO` and `ERROR` messages in Travis CI log file. I don't want this information should be printed on my Travis Log File.

Could you please help me how to remove this kind of information from Log file. Do we have any command to disable this log printing?

Thanks!!

Comment: Link to an example, please.

Comment: ERRO[0337] HTTP Error                                    err=no such id: simple statusCode=404

INFO[0337] POST /containers/simple/kill

Comment: Does the word "link" mean *anything* to you?

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved after applying > /dev/null 2&1 in the docker daemon. Below is the command.

sudo docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:$port -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock > /dev/null 2>&1 &

Now I am not seeing any INFO and ERRO messages in my Travis Log file.